# WMS / PIM for fashion retail

Tags: magento-1.9, product, products, products-management

I know this isn't specific a magento question, yet its highly magento related. So here goes:

We are looking for a WMS and/or PIM that handles the following:

- A fashion oriented WMS/PIM system
- A connection with magento.
- Connection to mulitple warehouses and physical stores.
- It should be possible to shift the stock internally
- The connection between the Warehouses/stocks and the WMS/PIM and Magento should be bi-directional
- Seperation of product availability betweeen region / location
- Integration with one or multiple POS systems
- Should/Could handle with multiple VAT's

Are there any wms systems that are multi national orientated and does (mostly) what we want here?
Why is that system good, why not? Or would you go for a different approach?

Detailed explanations below.

Example (shorter) version of the wanted setup.

[image: Diagram of the stores]
Full skitch screenshot here: https://www.evernote.com/l/AEInt5p3ynNLH6vtTOGeusNG-I1HDwY0Gjo

> ***Example 1:)***
>
> - Customer comes into the physical store, sees that a product that is on the website isn't there.
> - Customer/Salesclerk orders from the webshop and delivers it to the store.
>
>   - Internally the shift of the stock should go from **warehouse UK** to **UK store Stock**
> - Customer picks up the order from the store.

---

> ***Example 2:***
>
> - Customer lives on west coast of US and sees an product is in store in the UK store.
> - Its should not be possible for this customer to order the product
> - It could however be in stock in one of the physical stores in the US
>
>   - Depending on the location of the store it should be possible to:
>
>     1. Able to order it and let it be deliverd to his home/picked up in store
>     2. Not be able to order it

---

> ***Example 3:***
>
> - Customer orders 5 products in webshop.
>
>   - Depending on setting the product or delivery method (e.g. deliver to home or pickup at store) it should do the following
>   - Pickup:
>
>     - Store has 3 in stock, 2 has to be ordered from the warehouse and delivered into the store.
>     - Customer gets the products and Stock in store is reduced to 0
>   - Home delivery
>
>     - If product should be shipped from store?
>
>       - Warehouse sends 2 products to the customer
>       - Store sends 3 products to the customer
>     - If not
>
>       - All products are send from a warehouse if the store don't have enough items.
>       - Optionally if the store has the full order in stock, send from store. (through setting)

**Abbreviations:**

- UK: United Kingdom
- US: United States
- WMS: Warehouse Management System
- POS: Point of Sale
- PIM: Product Information Management